# POSIX Awk sort array

Tags: awk, sort, array, posix

I would like to sort an array with POSIX Awk, however I have discovered that:

- `asort()`
- `asorti()`
- `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]`

are all GNU extensions. Can this be done with without GNU Awk?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209462/recursive-calls-with-awk-failing for a head start...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
function arr_sort(ary,   x, y, z) {
  for (x in arr) {
    y = arr[x]
    z = x - 1
    while (z && arr[z] > y) {
      arr[z + 1] = arr[z]
      z--
    }
    arr[z + 1] = y
  }
}
```

[Source](//github.com/svnpenn/stdlib/blob/46a4e00/libstd.awk#L32-L42)